# UCT IMS Client Makefile doesnt work

Tags: gcc, makefile, libvlc

When I use `make` command it gives me this

```
 gcc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/lib/vlc/include/ `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 gstreamer-0.10` -o obj/callbacks.o -c src/callbacks.c
 In file included from src/callbacks.c:6:
 src/includes.h:29:37: error: gst/interfaces/xoverlay.h: No such file or directory
 src/includes.h:40:21: error: vlc/vlc.h: No such file or directory
 src/includes.h:41:28: error: vlc/deprecated.h: No such file or directory
 src/includes.h:42:24: error: vlc/libvlc.h: No such file or directory
 src/includes.h:43:35: error: vlc/libvlc_structures.h: No such file or directory
 In file included from src/includes.h:202,
             from src/callbacks.c:6:
 src/extern_vars.h:111: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
 src/extern_vars.h:112: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
 make: *** [obj/callbacks.o] Error 1
```

I have downloaded from here
http://sourceforge.net/projects/uctimsclient.berlios/

Comment: You appear to be missing a number of the required header files. Namely for the VLC library and GStreamer. What does `pkg-config --modversion gstreamer-0.10` output/return for you? Do you have the `/usr/lib/vlc/include` path?

Comment: 'pkg-config --modversion gstreamer-0.10'  output :
0.10.29
I have '/usr/lib/vlc' file and it has files : 'lua  plugins  vlc-cache-gen'  there is no include file.

Comment: What does `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-01.0` output? And it sounds like you need to install the VLC library development headers/package.

Comment: output is : 
    `Package gstreamer-01.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'gstreamer-01.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gstreamer-01.0' found`

Comment: Bah, typo in that command. Run `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-0.10` please. Also run `locate xoverlay.h`.

Comment: output of that comment : `-pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2  `
also I runned that `locate xoverlay.h` command

Comment: Did the `locate` command output anything? It should have listed the path to the `xoverlay.h` file it is existed. If it didn't output anything then the file wasn't there and that's part of the problem. The other part of the problem is that you are still missing the VLC headers. Do you have the `gstreamer-plugins-base-devel` package installed (for gstreamer)?

Comment: I installed this packages and solved the problem.However,I cannot run the application.Here is the result : `./uctimsclient: error while loading shared libraries: libeXosip2.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Also I installed "libeXosip2-3.1.0" but error continues.

Comment: Did the package you installed contain the library you needed? What does `ldd uctimsclient` say?

Answer (score 0):

This package needs VLC and GStreamer development files (headers and libs) to be compiled from source. What OS do you use?

Comment: Can you install those devel files?

Comment: I installed this packages and solved the problem.However,I cannot run the application.Here is the result : `./uctimsclient: error while loading shared libraries: libeXosip2.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
Also I installed "libeXosip2-3.1.0" but error continues.

Comment: Can you try to run it by specifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH?